# Best way to read a QString line by line

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I want to create a grep function (like grep in bash) for a qstring in c ++. So I need a loop where I can read the QString line by line. What is the best way? Do you have to go through the QString letter by letter and test whether a \ n occurs or is there a simpler / faster / shorter way?

```
QString Text = "Line1\nLine2\n";
Loop {
    std::cout << Line.toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

This should be the Output:

```
Line1
Line2
```

Comment: One way is  using `QString::split()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348292/qstringsplit-and-r-n-and-r-n-convention

Comment: [`QTextStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea from @thuga and @drescherjm

```
    QString TXT="l1\nl2\nl3\nl4", Line;
    QTextStream stream(&TXT);

    while (stream.readLineInto(&Line)) {
        std::cout <<Line.toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    //Set the device to pos 0
    stream.seek(0);
```

Output:

```
l1
l2
l3
l4
```

```
    QString TXT="l1\nl2\nl3\nl4";
    QStringList Lines = TXT.split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < Lines.size(); i++) {
        std::cout <<Lines[i].toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
l1
l2
l3
l4
```

Comment: Know anyone what is faster?

Comment: You can try measuring to see which performs faster.

Comment: I agree benchmark to figure this out. Note that you will likely have to make the string much larger to determine that (because the result will take a very small amount of time with such a small example). Also make sure you turn on optimizations. I have seen cases where the Debug mode of Visual Studio took 100 times as long to execute as the Release mode.

Comment: For large texts at least, the `QTextStream` helper should be faster, and consume less memory as well.